# Uncountable subspaces of the real line

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

**Definition 1.** A topological space $\langle X, \tau \rangle$ is meager if $X = \bigcup_{n \in \omega}A_n$, where each $A_n$ is nowhere dense in $\langle X, \tau \rangle$.

**Definition 2.** A topological space is of the second category if it is non-meager.

**Definition 3.** A topological space is perfect if it does not contain isolated points.

I have the following question about the second category property of uncountable subspaces of the real line:

**Question.** Is it provable in ZFC (is it consistent with ZFC) that every perfect uncountable subspace of the real line contains a perfect uncountable subspace that is of the second category?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen  This space is of the second category because it is complete metric space

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Cantor set is of first category as a subset of $\mathbb R$, but is second category in itself.

Comment: Do you mean second category in $\Bbb R$ or second category in itself (i.e. Baire)? That makes a big difference.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, yes, i mean second category in itself

Comment: It is certainly not provable in ZFC, since under Martin's Axiom, every subset of $\mathbb R$ of size less than the continuum is meager.

Comment: @Anonymous, is it meager in itself?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't this follow from the fact that every uncountable perfect subsets of the reals contains a Cantor space?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, a counterexample to your statement is the Bernstein set

Comment: @Smolin A Bernstein set isn't perfect, since it isn't closed (in fact a Bernstein set isn't even Borel because of the same reason: every borel subset of the reals is either countable or it contains a Cantor set)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, i define perfect space (Definition 3 in my question) as a topological space without isolated points

Comment: Yes, under MA every subset of $\mathbb R$ of size less than the continuum is meager in itself.

Comment: If you don't require perfect sets to be closed let $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ be perfect uncountable. If $A$ contains an uncountable closed set, then $A$ contains a Cantor set, otherwise $A$ is a Bernstein set, and Bernstein sets are [Baire spaces](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/), so second category in themselves

Comment: @Anonymous, do you mean subsets without isolated points? Because there exists a countable subset of the real line with isolated points that is of the second category in itself. Could you give please some link?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, it is not clear why is it true that either set contains a Cantor subspace or is a Bernstein set, because by definition in your link, set is a Bernstein set iff it and its complement intersect with every Cantor space, i.e. it is not enough does not contain a cantor subspace in order to be a Bernstein set

Comment: Yes, I should have said every subset of size less than the continuum without isolated points.  I think that this is in Miller's article in the Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology.

Comment: This is a good question -- not sure why someone voted to close it. (@Anonymous is right about what happens under MA -- so that bit is solved -- but I really like the "is it consistent" part of the question. I wonder what happens under CH?)

Comment: @WillBrian But CH implies MA, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Correct. And in case CH holds, the statement of Anonymous becomes "under MA every *countable* subset of $\mathbb R$ is meager in itself." Notice that we're talking about sets of size *less than* $\mathfrak{c}$, not $\leq\!\mathfrak{c}$. (I suppose we should add "without isolated points" to make this true, although in the context of this question that was probably just assumed.)

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Oh, but now I understand your point a bit better. The comment of Anonymous solves the problem assuming MA+$\neg$CH, because then there are uncountable subsets of $\mathbb R$ with size $<\!\mathfrak{c}$. Under CH, MA technically still holds, but it doesn't apply directly to uncountable sets.